# How can I confidently state the error of a specific test is within a range with a 95% confidence interval

Tags: confidence-interval, variance, t-test, standard-deviation, standard-error

I have a test that provides values with known amounts of error. For instance the error on the test

(Value - TrueValue) = -7.62, -9.33, -8.36, -9.79,-10.45, -9.51, -10.83, -10.64, -9.96, -10.30

I want to try to linearly adjust the value to reflect the true value by correcting for the average error. In this case, the average error is **-9.679,** so adjusting for this the new errors are:

2.059, 0.349, 1.319, -0.111, -0.771, 0.169, -1.151, -0.961, -0.281, -0.621

How can I state with confidence that given any new test, adjusted by the error, its true value is within X given 95% confidence? What sort of test would I want to use? Can anyone provide a resource to read about this topic? Thank you

Comment: The general topic is known as "calibration" in some literature, such as that of chemometrics.  Part of the answer lies in a consideration of whether future tests will continue to exhibit the same mean error: this is the question of *drift.* The other part is a matter of defining what you mean by "confidence," considering how many future test results you will obtain, and constructing a suitable *prediction interval.*  This accounts both for the random error in all the new tests as well as the uncertainty in the adjustment value.

Comment: @whuber Thank you for these terms, researching prediction intervals it seems to mainly involve having an input variable and predicting an interval of the output. What would my input variable be in this case? My input is the received value and my output is the true value? Is it possible to say that for ALL inputs, the error will be less than X with 95% confidence?

Comment: Your input variable is the difference between `value` and `truevalue`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to provide a Bayesian approach.

Let $y$ be the error between the measurement and the truth.  If you're willing to make assumptions about the error (maybe that the measurement is biased in some way, that bias needs estimation, and there is additional noise in the process) it may be possible to select a distribution with which to model the errors.  Let's assume for the sake of exposition that a Student t distribution is good enough for our purposes, but any distribution will do.

The model is then

$$ y \sim B + \epsilon $$

Here $B$ is the bias of the measurement and $\epsilon$ is a student t random variable with some degree of freedom, $\nu$, which requires estimation from the data.  There are two sources of variation we need to account for: variation in the estimate of $B$ *as well* as variation in the estimate of the degrees of freedom for $\epsilon$ (or whatever other parameter is used in your choice or error distribution.  This could be $\sigma$ if you were to use a normal distribution).

To provide an interval estimator, we can leverage the *posterior predictive distribution* [which I have talked about in this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/558859/is-the-t-test-to-test-the-difference-from-0/558862#558862).  IN essence, we will draw values of $B$ and $\nu$ from our posterior and then use those to simulate new data from our likelihood.  Once we do that a couple thousand times, we can summarize the resulting distribution using quantiles to give an interval estimator.

Here is how we might do this with your data

```
library(brms)

# Data you have provided
errors = c(-7.62, -9.33, -8.36, -9.79,-10.45, -9.51, -10.83, -10.64, -9.96, -10.30)
d = data.frame(errors)

# Fit a Bayesian model with a student t error
model = brm(errors~1, data = d, family = student())

# Sample from the posterior predictive
posterior_predictions = posterior_predict(model, newdata = list(1))

# Summarize a 95% credible interval 
quantile(posterior_predictions, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))

      2.5%      97.5% 
-12.377867  -7.049977
```

The result is an interval which contains 95% probability for seeing a new observation given the model specification.  That's our uncertainty in the prediction.  We can also summarize our uncertainty in the bias (much like a confidence interval) in a similar way

```
B = posterior_samples(model, pars = 'Intercept')[, 1]
quantile(B, probs = c(0.025, 0.975))
     2.5%      97.5% 
-10.439664  -8.974423 

mean(B)
[1] -9.72698
```

So our estimate of the bias is -9.76 (this will depedn on how many samples you use as well as a few other things not worth mentioning here) and our uncertainty in that bias is given by the credible interval (-10.44 --  -8.97).

The benefit of this approach is integrating over all uncertainty in the model, not *just* uncertainty in the parameters the model as would be done with a frequentist prediction interval.  However, Bayesian models require a bit of a learning curve to get used to.

Answer (score 1):

Put it this way....

You test #1

> (Value - TrueValue) = -7.62, -9.33, -8.36, -9.79,-10.45, -9.51, -10.83, -10.64, -9.96, -10.30

And the averaged-error/adjustment is `-9.679`. If you conduct 1000 tests, you will have 1000 different values of averaged-error/adjustment. Then you can plot the distribution and it would probably be a normal distribution. Then you can calculate the `mean` and the `standard deviation` of this distribution, and you can say that the averaged-error/adjustment is `mean +/- 2*standard-deviation` with 95% confidence.